# Результат сравнения строки и true

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, почему в следующем коде выводится false

```js
const data = true;
console.log(data == "true");
```

ведь, если data приводится к строке, то получается

```js
console.log("true" == "true");
```

а, если "true" приводится к булеву типу, то получается

```js
const data = true;
console.log(data == true);
```

в обоих случаях выдается true. Почему в первом варианте на выходе false?

Comment: Потому что data приводится к числу 1, а строка true приводится к числу NaN. Так в стандарте

Comment: ты сравниваешь два разных типа

Comment: @Alexey Ten т.е. здесь как в си только одно неявное преобразование? А где в стандарте посмотреть можно?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 пункт 6, а потом п. 4

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion

Comment: @Alexey пункт 6, а потом п. 4 - все понятно, спасибо.

Comment: В одном из ответов на `Возможный дупликат вопроса`: **undefined, null при преобразовании в boolean превращаются в false, но это не означает, что они равны false**   О, боги, верните мне мой с++ )))

Comment: @tilin в вашем с++ такая же фигня с нулевым указателем. Существуют платформы где нулевой указатель численно равен -1, но обозначается он всегда как 0.

Comment: @tilin а уж что можно устроить с переопределением операторов...